# simulating touch event on system android java

Tags: java, android

```
package net.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.muxic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.app.Service.START_STICKY;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //System.out.println(isConnected(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(isConnected(this)) {
            //startActivity(new Intent("com.google.music"));

            /*Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(i);*/
            View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.layoutView);

            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            lock.disableKeyguard();

            view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
            {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "View touched",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    );
                    toast.show();

                    return true;
                }
            });


// Obtain MotionEvent object
            long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
            float x = 0.0f;
            float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
            int metaState = 0;
            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    downTime,
                    eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    x,
                    y,
                    metaState
            );

// Dispatch touch event to view
            view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        Log.d("[DEBUG]", "X: " + x + "Y: " + y);

        return true;
    }

    public void fox(View v){
        Log.d("[DEBUG]", "X: " + v.getPivotX() + ", Y: " + v.getPivotY());
    }

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
        return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
    }
}
```

---

***What I want to Achieve***
Main goal is to be able to check if the user is connected to a device, if TRUE then redirect the user to HOME in which there is a widget waiting to be a pressed. Afterwards fire an event that will automatically touch the widget to start playing the music.
**NOTE**: The music part is done by a separate app. That's why I have the app redirect to HOME (Triggered/Redirected through intent.) and then execute the button press at X: (coordinate X here) and Y: (coordinate Y here).

I don't care if I have to root, sign with platform key, and all that since I will be the only one that will be using it.

---

***What have I done?***

- Searched google for over an hour. Found a bunch of tutorials, but most of them are outdated and is not noob proof. However, the code below is in fact from other stackoverflow questions. (Since what I did was simply google what I needed to do, and started mashing them together in hopes that it would work.)
- Looked at StackOverflow for answers about *Simulating Touch Events*, *Touch Events android*, *MotionEvent for android java*, *Signing app with system permission for touch event*, etc.

**NOTE**: As mentioned most of the stuff I've seen are old (2010-2014). Since when I tried to find the system_signature, it was not in the directory mentioned in another stackoverflow question. If you guys could just give me a small pointer, that'd be really helpful!

---

**EXTRA**: I'm also having issue with making it check every X second if the 'connected' status has changed. If it has don't do anything until it's connected again. (I believe this is done through background service thing. As per said just give me a proper name to google and I'll do my own research, or if you give me a definite answer that'd be helpful too.) [NOT NEEDED, but would be cool.]

---

***IMAGE UI***

[Widget UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QLI7.png) - Hopefully this will help you get an idea of what I'm trying to press.

Comment: Have you at least looked at monkeyrunner? See: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/MonkeyDevice.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have not! I thought it was a non-android thing. I'm looking at it right now.